# What's the proof that $\sqrt {AB} = \sqrt A \times \sqrt B$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, exponentiation

Sorry for simple questions, just trying to understand the basics. I suppose since  $\sqrt x = x^{\frac12}$ the proof must be the same as: $$(AB)^x =A^x \times B^x $$ But then how do you prove that?

Comment: you ask why $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{y}$? Just square both sides of the equation (this is allowed because both sides are positive).

Comment: for $A,B\geq 0$

Answer (score 0):

The minimal set of axioms to define exponentiation are ..
$$ x^1=x \\ x^ax^b=x^{a+b}$$

from which you can prove the rule $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$

From here we can prove your result using $y=x^{log_x y}$

$$ (xy)^a=(x\times x^{\log_xy})^a 
\\=x^{a+a\log_x y}
\\ = x^a y^a $$